# Converting logs to JSON format

Tags: go

```
    klog.Info("kube config file loaded ")
```

is there a way to convert logs to JSON format in Go?
I tried ,

```
    klog.info(json.Marshal("kube config file loaded"))
```

but did not got output in json.help me out

Comment: What is  klog? You might want to try a third-party logging package, like github.com/sirupsen/logrus that supports json logging.

Comment: [klog](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog) default output is in the [format](https://play.golang.org/p/Mq22ArUtiBg) ```I1110 23:00:00.000000       3 prog.go:26] kube config file loaded ```. How would you like this output? (please provide the output you are aiming for). As @BurakSerdar says moving to a logger that targets json, such as [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus), [zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) or [zerolog](https://github.com/rs/zerolog), would probably be your best option.

Comment: i want the output in json format like{{ "type":"info", "date-time":"23:00:00.000000"}}

Comment: In that case definitly look at using a different logging package. To get that format you would need to rewrite significant portions of klog ([e.g.](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog/blob/master/klog.go#L568))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klog doesnt support json formatting